# LitElement - Don't add attribute if value is false

Tags: javascript, css, lit-element

Is there a way to basically render these three possibilities:

```html
<my-el someValue="a"></my-el>
<my-el someValue="b"></my-el>
<my-el></my-el>
```

Note the explicit lack of the attribute `someValue` on the third.

To render this normally I would do:

```js
render() {
  const someValue = "a";

  return html`
    <my-el someValue=${someValue}></my-el>
  `;
}
```

But if `someValue` was `undefined`, it would render as `<my-el someValue="undefined"></my-el>` which I don't want.

Is there a way to get boolean-like behavior for falsy, but show the value for truthy values? I read the docs, but hopefully I'm missing something.

The reason I want to do this is because I'd like to have a CSS selector that affects all of them that have `[someValue]` regardless of what the actual value is, but to not apply that if it isn't there.

P.S., I'm aware of workarounds like using `:not([someValue=undefined])` or returning conditional HTML, so please don't reply with those. I'm using one of those right now, but if there is a direct answer to my question, hoping to swap out for that for a little cleaner code. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use [`ifDefined`](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#ifdefined) directive for this. For AttributeParts, it sets the attribute if the `someValue` is defined and removes the attribute if the `someValue` is undefined. You can then further modify it using ternary operator to check for *falsy* values as well:

```
import {ifDefined} from 'lit-html/directives/if-defined';

return html`
   <my-el someValue=${ifDefined(someValue ? someValue : undefined)}></my-el>
`;
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2023 / Lit2

https://lit.dev/docs/templates/conditionals/#conditionally-rendering-nothing

```
import { html, nothing } from 'lit';

return html`<my-el some-value=${someValue || nothing}></my-el>`
```

This will only render the `some-value` attribute if the `someValue` value is truthy.

*(I've taken the liberty to write the attribute in kebab-case to hopefully make it a little less confusing what's what.)*